# Building Flask app - sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I am doing a project on a tutorial - I am suppose to build a flask app; a book review website.

I have stumbled upon this problem for many hours and I am left clueless. It does seem like I have some lack of understanding under SQL and foreign keys.

**The error is throwing this message:**
`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update on table "reviews" violates foreign key constraint "reviews_id_fkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) is not present in table "users". [SQL: INSERT INTO reviews (username, review, rating, date) VALUES (%(username)s, %(review)s, %(rating)s, %(date)s)] [parameters: {'username': 'katal90', 'review': 'hello', 'rating': '3', 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 16, 18, 33, 332614)}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)`

**Here's the route where the issue is happening.**

```py
@app.route('/book/<string:isbn>', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def book(isbn):
    #import columns from database 
    res = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()
    #import api from Goodreads (stats) 
    r = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "L3FHyOR3IhCo3kctcUz3zg", "isbns": isbn})
    if r.status_code != 200:
      raise ValueError
    reviews_count=r.json()["books"][0]["reviews_count"]
    average_rating=r.json()["books"][0]["average_rating"]
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = session.get("username")
        review = request.form.get("comment")
        rating = request.form.get("rating")
        date = datetime.now()
        db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (username, review, rating, date) VALUES (:username, :review, :rating, :date)", {"date":date, "review":review, "rating":rating, "username":username})
        db.commit()
    return render_template("book.html", reviews_count = reviews_count, average_rating = average_rating)
```

**Here's the entire SQL tables. in order for you to see what is happening with the structure; specially foreign keys.**

[image: review table]
[image: users table]
[image: book table]

It seems to me that I am having a serious lack of understanding how Foreign Key should work and I would like to ask for some advises on the topic. 
How should foreign keys relate to each other and why's the error message looking for id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have declared the primary key of `reviews` table as a foreign key to `users`, which is not right. You should add a new column, say, `user_id` to the `reviews` table and make that a FK to `user.id` instead.

Then you should find out the current user's id (by looking it up using the `users` table) and include that id in your `INSERT` clause, for example:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (user_id, username, review, rating, date) VALUES (:user_id, :username, :review, :rating, :date)", {"user_id": user_id, "date":date, "review":review, "rating":rating, "username":username})
```

As a side note, the `username` column is redundant for the `reviews` table as you already have a FK relation to the `users` table. If, for example, a `username` is changed in the `users` table it will not be automatically reflected to the `reviews` records for that user. It is recommended to normalise the table by removing that column and looking it up using the relation when needed.

Comment: How should I pass the `user.id` to the route? do i have to pass in as an argument like `{(url_for='index', user.id = user.id)}` upon login? thanks for taking the time to troubleshoot together..

Comment: You can do that, or you can simply use the `username` to perform an extra `SELECT` on the `users` table.

Comment: I tried getting id by putting `id= session.get("id")` just like how I successfully got the username. But no luck...

Comment: why is getting session `username` works but for `id` it doesnt?

Comment: I can't comment on this because I don't know how you handle user logins. Are you using a third party package or did you implement your own authentication method? The session does not get populated magically, some mechanism should store the data there after login.

Comment: im just using flask session.